# How do you create a new form for a custom Content Type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type, sharepoint-api

I am creating a new content type through an Elements.xml file in Visual Studio.  I have reference a custom New form document in the XmlDocment node

```
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
    <FormTemplates  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
      <Display>ListForm</Display>
      <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
      <New>MyNewList</New>
    </FormTemplates>
  </XmlDocument>
```

Now when I create a new instance of the Content Type, I get a blank.  I have read that this New nodes should reference a ASCX control.   However I have not found any good examples that walk me through the process.

Answer (score 0):

The value you specify in your `<New></New>` element is the ID of a `RenderingTemplate` control in the _controltemplates directory. If you open

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates.ascx
```

you'll see the rendering templates SharePoint uses, including `ListForm`. You can create your own rendering template by creating a new ASCX file in the same directory. [This is an article](http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2011/09/04/customizing-listitem-forms-using-renderingtemplates/) that walks you through doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex... For you Answer.

I learned the difference between using FormTemplates vs. FormUrls elements.  The FormsTemplate is used to references a custom user control, using the existing aspx page.  This is described by the Link Alex provided.  A coworked pointed in the direction of using FormUrls.  FormUrls is used to references an entirely new aspx page.

```
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
    <FormUrls xmlns:dd= "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
      <New>_layouts/TMF/NewJobCard.aspx</New>
    </FormUrls>
  </XmlDocument>
```